# Trying to implement a simple JSON web service in Java

Tags: java, json, rest, wildfly

I'm trying to implement a java JSON webservice on wildfly and failing miserably...

Ok, this is what I currently have:

my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>ReportBuilderBack</display-name>  
</web-app>
```

my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>reportbuilderback</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.test.reportbuilderback</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>async-http-servlet-3.0</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

My configapp.java:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class ConfigApp extends Application {
    //intentionally left blank

}
```

My POJO class:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.test.reportbuilderback.dao.UserDao;
import org.test.reportbuilderback.models.User;

@Path("/userwebservice")
public class UserWebService {

    @Path("/users")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response listUsers(){
        List<User>allUsers=new UserDao().getAllUsers();
        return Response.status(200).entity(allUsers).build();               
    }

}
```

This all deploys without errors to Wildfly 10.x.
However, when going to http://localhost:8080/org.test.reportbuilderback/rest/userwebservice/users, I just get a 404.

I just can't get my head around what I'm doing wrong here. Can any give some pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT:
By request, server log output added.

```
19:43:43,517 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.2.Final
19:43:43,977 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
19:43:44,113 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) starting
19:43:46,605 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found org.test.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called org.test.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.dodeploy
19:43:46,753 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
19:43:46,778 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO version 3.4.0.Final
19:43:46,806 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.4.0.Final
19:43:47,016 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
19:43:47,066 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
19:43:47,070 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.21.Final
19:43:47,080 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
19:43:47,083 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
19:43:47,087 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
19:43:47,107 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
19:43:47,164 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
19:43:47,239 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
19:43:47,619 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.0.Final starting
19:43:47,640 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
19:43:47,681 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.4.Final)
19:43:47,656 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
19:43:47,680 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.6.Final
19:43:47,726 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
19:43:48,000 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/home/wouter/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
19:43:48,223 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
19:43:48,236 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
19:43:48,297 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
19:43:48,297 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
19:43:48,541 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
19:43:49,251 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
19:43:49,440 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /home/wouter/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
19:43:49,559 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /home/wouter/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments
19:43:49,571 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "org.test.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "org.test.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
19:43:49,903 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.4.Final
19:43:49,973 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
19:43:49,965 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
19:43:49,990 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
19:43:49,992 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
19:43:49,995 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
19:43:49,997 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
19:43:50,066 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
19:43:50,664 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.5.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.6) 
19:43:53,379 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment org.test.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
19:43:53,521 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
19:43:54,035 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000900: 2.3.5 (Final)
19:43:57,775 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.test.reportback.webservices.ConfigApp
19:43:57,853 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /org.test.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
19:43:57,924 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "org.test.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "org.test.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
19:43:58,170 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
19:43:58,171 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
19:43:58,172 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started in 15315ms - Started 475 of 723 services (404 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
19:43:57,775 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.test.reportback.webservices.ConfigApp
19:43:57,853 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /org.test.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

In log, web context is : `/org.test.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`
You should use that in your url :

```
 http://localhost:8080/org.test.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/rest/userwebservice/users
```

or

```
 http://localhost:8080/org.test.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/userwebservice/users
```

if `@ApplicationPath("/rest")` is ignored for any reason by your rest api.

Comment: Nope, sorry, still a 404. Not using Spring framework here by the way, just trying to deploy using jax-rs on wildfly.
Also tried to put a System.out.println("test"); in that method listUsers. Whether I try my URL or yours, never gets called...

Comment: You will find :) In the server log or output, all is ok ? No error is traced ? You mmay add server log output in the original message. It may be helpful

Comment: Added output from server logs. From deployment up until trying your and my URL multiple times. As I said, no output printed to console.

Comment: In the log, we have an interesting information. I updated the post to give some guessworks.

Comment: I told you you would found :) Great :)